# Custom URL %link next_post_link and previous_post_link Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like to customize the URL link generated by next_post_link() and previous_post_link()  (Wordpress post Navigation Functions)

Now returns a  URL link like this: 
http://wwww.misite.com/notice1 (for example)

I would like returns a custom URL link like this:
http://www.misite.com/shop/notice1

My code is :

```
$content .= next_post_link('<div class="nav-prev">&laquo; %link</div>'); 
$content .= previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link &raquo;</div>');
```

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: The first post just been edited

Comment: Do you understand WordPress filters?  There are two - `next_post_link` and `previous_post_link` - that should allow you to alter the URL; sadly I can't find documentation for them in the Codex, or I'd have posted an answer.  The arguments are `$output` (what you're seeing replacing %link, above), `$format`, `$link`, `$post`.  Depending on your exact requirement, you _may_ be able to just replace `misite.com/` with `misite.com/shop/` in `$output` and return that from the filter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to retrieve the result of function that don't return anything. See the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) for more info about these functions.

If you want to store the link, you can use the `get_next_posts_link()` function instead (see [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_posts_link)). You can also find `get_previous_posts_link()`.

Comment: Finnally solved using get_next_post_link() and get_previous_post_link() (post in singular) , when i store the link, i modify using preg_replace and always perfect! Thxs!